# Why does the status bar not display counts for IMAP folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010, the status bar does not display item and unread counts for imap account folders but does for local folders (personal folders).

These counts used to be displayed for all folders regardless of type of account in Outlook 2007.

Do I need to tweak a customizable option somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

It could mean your filter is on so your view only display a portion of all your email.  Double click on the status bar to bring up the filter dialog box and clear the filter function.  It works for me...

Answer (score -1):

In Outlook 2010, the status bar does not display item and unread counts.

Comment: Yes it does.  Try right clicking the statusbar to see the options, but it does by default on mine.

Answer (score -1):

My set up shows 'Filter Applied' lower left hand corner. Click that and select 'clear all'.  My counts for e-mail per account now show.  Hope this helps.